# JSON Parsing to ListView Android

Tags: android, json, listview

I have a problem to parsing from JSON to Listview in Android. This is an example of data from JSON :

```
[{
    "area": "Kebon Jeruk",
    "city": "Jakarta"
}, {
    "area": "Puri",
    "city": "Jakarta"
}, {
    "area": "Grogol",
    "city": "Jakarta"
}]
```

and I want to make ListView like this :

[image]

Thank you very much.

Comment: what is the issue ? any error or something else ?

Comment: I'm confused how to parsing that data, because this is first time I want to parsing JSON @KhizarHayat...

Comment: follow some tutorial like [http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm]

Answer (score 1):

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(yourJSONresponse);
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++){
    String info = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("area") + arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("city");
    list.add(info);
}
```

And then just turn the List into an Array of Strings, and use an adapter to fill the `ListView` like so:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.ListView,StringArray);
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Thank you very much @jack-ryan. Can you give me some link for full tutorial for make this ?

Comment: Yep, here is some documentation for the standard `JSON` libraries in Java/Android: https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

Comment: And here is a brief tutorial for ListView in Android: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_list_view.htm

Comment: No problem, if you are satisfied with the answer you can mark it accepted. Also here is one more for the `JSONArray` I used in the example. https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html

Answer (score 0):

Remaining on your own

```
try {
        ArrayList<User> list = new ArrayList<>();
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(url);
        for (int i = 0; i <array.length() ; i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = array.optJSONObject(i);
            String area = jsonObject.optString("area");
            String city = jsonObject.optString("city");
            list.add(new User(area,city));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

class User {
    String area;
    String city;
    public User(String area,String city){
        this.area=area;
        this.city=city;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much @cgx, I will try this

Answer (score 0):

make changes in ur layoutxml file take two text boxes beside this will work